# Magento 2 static files missing issue

Tags: magento2, server-setup, apache2

i have setp up magento 2.2 on apache server , my static files url are like :

```
<script  type="text/javascript"  src="http://example.com/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/requirejs/require.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript"  src="http://example.com/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/mage/requirejs/mixins.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript"  src="http://example.com/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/requirejs-config.js"></script>
```

and clicking  on those (static files ) it shows **"Whoops, our bad..."**

Now when i remove  code from both  .htaccess files (outside and inside pub folder ) it started working fine , i want to know why this line is causing issue .

```
<Files *>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is apache versioning. You can get more details from the above GitHub link https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10810

These changes are made as per security prospect to improve the direct file access algorithm.